# Sharepoint lists linked to SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I am currently running two seperate servers one for sharepoint and one with SQL Server, however they are on the same domain. I'm hoping to dynamically link the sharepoint lists to update their corresponding tables on the SQL server database. Is this possible? If so, what should I research into in order to get that to work?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying the Business Connectivity Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx ?
You will need to use the SharePoint Designer to create an External Content Type which will use a chosen identity (Windows account, for ex.) to connect to your SQL Server instance.
Then, you can create a list from the External Content Type.

Or, you can create a Business Data Connectivity Model as your External Content Type with Visual Studio 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/Video/ff623022
This maybe more flexible if you don't mind coding.

The list and the SQL Server data can sync with each other by using the BCS.